# Remove ticks / tiny white line from colorbar ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

how to remove that white line from a ggplot2 colourbar?

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10))+
theme(legend.key.height=unit(2,"line"))
```

generates this plot

[image]

But if you zoom in the legend, you will see tiny annoying white lines:

[image]

How can I remove them? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `ticks.colour=` within `guide_colorbar()` by referencing via `guides()`... here ya go:

```
# where "plot" = your plot code...
plot + guides(fill=guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = "black"))
```

[image]

And to remove them, set the color to `NA`:

```
plot + guides(fill=guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: that guides stuff is new to me. many thanks!